# fetch via URL request blocked using nextjs and vercel

Tags: firebase, next.js, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, vercel

I am trying to fetch a csv file via URL (nextjs api route) and while it works locally, the deployed version on vercel seems to block it. To be precise I am using d3 ( d3.csv() ) in the api route, but after deploying on vercel the d3 fetch fails:

`api/xx` (using d3:)

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
 ...
    const key = push(setRef).key;
        if (key) {
          const storageURL: string =
            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis...'; // --> public
    
          await csv(storageURL)  // --> this fails
            .then(async data => {
              ...
```

called like this:

```
const refreshData = () => {
    replace(asPath);
  };

  const addGuess = async () => {
    await fetch(`${server}/api/xx?id=${currentUser.uid}`, {
      method: 'POST',
    });
    refreshData(); // --> probably not relevant
  };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My best guess is that you're using the "official" production hostname then loading the frontend from a preview hostname. Why do you need to prepend `${server}` to the fetch url? What's wrong about doing just `fetch("/api/....")`?

Comment: @ffflabs Is it possible that there is a problem with receiving the csv threw the url because vercel blocks loading data threw links like these?

Comment: I remember reading SSR + calls to api is redundant, but  I have seldomly used next.js and always for simple sites. Serverless functions shouldn't enforce CORS, but then again the fact they reside in `pages/api` instead of `api` suggest my vercel-fu doesn't necessarily apply here. ¿Don't you need to polyfill fetch?

Comment: @ffflabs Sorry for constantly commenting.. I am a bit in a hurry.. :)

I found this:
https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions & https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8251

So as I understand it, vercel never even loads the file and as d3 expects a URL the workaround mentioned in the github-discussion is no fix for this.

Or am I totally on the wrong path here?

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing the CORS error? The error message mentions a fetch made from origin `https://xx-xxxgh7-txxo5.vercel.app` to `https://xx.vercel.app/api/xx?id=1Or7N2`, neither of these are related to the `storageURL` used in the `csv()` call. Seems to me the CORS error comes from the fetch you make inside `addGuess()`.

Comment: @juliomalves I updated the question - the error message was not relevant anymore. Sorry for that.. and thank you for your answer!

as you can see in my comment above I think the fetch inside of `d3()` is blocked by vercel. also I found the github issue [issue](github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8251) describing that files cannot be imported - now I am not sure if that includes fetching files.. or if there is a workaround for this particular fetching issue..

(I have tested it a few ways and can say that d3 fails fetching the csv only on vercel)